# java ThiledMap slick No OpenGL context found in the current thread

Tags: java, intellij-idea, opengl, slick2d, tiled

I want to use .tmx file as TiledMap

this is my main class:

```
package com.company;

import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;

public class Main {

    private static TiledMap map;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            init();
        }
        catch (SlickException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void init() throws SlickException {
        map = new TiledMap("com/company/untitled.tmx");
        map.render(100,100);
    }
}
```

I have the follow problem when I'm compile my program in intellij:

> Tue Jun 20 23:37:23 IRDT 2017 ERROR:No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)
>     at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glGetError(GL11.java:1377)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:226)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:171)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.Image.(Image.java:196)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TileSet.(TileSet.java:113)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.load(TiledMap.java:447)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.(TiledMap.java:90)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.(TiledMap.java:77)
>     at com.company.Main.init(Main.java:18)
>     at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:11)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply start rendering in the `init` method. You should override the `render` method and do the rendering there. At that point the OpenGL context should have been initialized by Slick2D.

```
public void render(GameContainer arg0, Graphics arg1) throws SlickException
```